# How to use java library from kotlin program?

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, unexpected-token

I am programming in Kotlin.

I need to use a library, which is written in **java** and comes from maven central.

I put the dependency in my `pom.xml` and can import the library in my **Kotlin** code.

However, I am not able to understand how I can use that java library from Kotlin.

From the tutorials, in **Java**, the library should be used as (it is used to generate PDF):

```
//Initialize writer
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(dest);

//Initialize document
PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document doc = new Document(pdfDoc);

//Add paragraph to the document
doc.add(new Paragraph("Hello World!"));

//Close document
doc.close();
```

But how should I do in Kotlin, I tried the following:

```
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter

class PDFService {
    
    fun generateSimplePdf(value: String) {
        println("I am generating a PDF for $value :)")
        val writer: PdfWriter(dest)

        val document: PdfDocument(writer)
    }
}
```

But the arguments of PdfWriter and PdfDocument give: "Unexpected token".

How should I do that ? In a more general way, is there a reference on how to use java inside kotlin ? (This [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/mixing-java-kotlin-intellij.html) is not very helpfull).

Comment: This has nothing to do with using Java classes in Kotlin. Your Kotlin syntax is incorrect. Use `val write = PdfWriter(dest)`. Note `=`, not `:`. Same with your document line. The colon is for specifying the type. An equal sign is for assigning a value. Type can usually be omitted because it can be inferred from what you initially assign.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, that makes sense. I should pay more attention to the documentation. If you write an answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Tenfour04 from the comments:

> This has nothing to do with using Java classes in Kotlin. Your Kotlin
> syntax is incorrect. Use `val write = PdfWriter(dest)`. Note `=`, not `:`.
> Same with your document line. The colon is for specifying the type. An
> equal sign is for assigning a value. Type can usually be omitted
> because it can be inferred from what you initially assign.